# Mouseover suddenly not working

Tags: mouse, monterey

my MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019, Intel x86_64) with macOS 12.1 Monterey seems to be encountering a very strange issue. Normally, when you move your mouse over a button in Chrome, or a menu button item, etc., the button will change its color, and depending on the exact area, perhaps the mouse cursor shape will change (for example, the icon over a link will change from an arrow to a pointing finger). Neither of these is happening for me for a few days now. I have no idea what might have caused this. Among other annoying effects, this means the "Automatically show and hide Dock" option doesn't work - the Dock is always hidden. The issue occurs both on my external USB mouse and my built-in trackpad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to have resolved itself for now by resetting NVRAM and SMC, and rebooting. No idea which of these steps actually did the trick.

Comment: The reboot. NVRAM & SMC had nothing to do with it.

Comment: I had a similar problem in Big Sur. Restarting did not fix the problem, but resetting the NVRAM did solve it.

Comment: Same thing happens occasionally to me also on Sonoma, and happened on Ventura, Monterey, and Big Sur as well. The restart always fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue which, based on my research, is pretty much corner side (not popular). Based on my experience, the reason is due to using an old wireless Logitech mouse (Performance MX). Basically, the old Logitech is incompatible with the new macOS (Monterey).

Solution:

1. Shut down my Mac
2. Removed the cable from the outlet, wait 20 min, plug it back in, and wait 5 min before starting up
3. Removed all peripherals and attach a simple wired mouse (Logitech M90)
4. Turn on my Mac and viola!! It is working fine.

The moment I connect my old mouse (Performance MX) it will go to the same situation.